# Issue retrieving id from mysql table after calculation in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a distance calculation query that works, i.e. it returns the closest points, but it simply yields an array of distances. What I want to do is retrieve the ids of the points stored in the array so I can access further data.

Here's the query:

```
$Eastings           = $asset->Eastings;
$Northings      = $asset->Northings;
$micromarket_size  = 10000;

$competitors    = DB::table('homes')
                    -> select(DB::raw('SQRT(POW('.$Eastings.' - `Eastings`,2) + POW('.$Northings.' - `Northings`,2)) AS distance'))
                    -> having('distance', '<', $micromarket_size)
                    -> get();
```

And trying to access the id like so:

```
$competitors->id;
```

yields an error `trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select query is not requesting the id field:

```
->select(array('id', DB::raw('SQRT(POW('.$Eastings.' - `Eastings`,2) + POW('.$Northings.' - `Northings`,2)) AS distance')))
```

Comment: You're the man, didn't know I could pass an array as arguments for the select clause!

Answer (score 0):

You get array of stdObjects using DB::table()->get(), thus if you want to retrieve only one model replace get() with first(). Otherwise get single element from array.

Comment: Still getting the same object with only a single parameter (distance): object(stdClass)#153 (1) { ["distance"]=> string(1) "0" }